# Why is the keyboard not rising in IOS8 for a text field with this code?

Tags: keyboard, ios8, uikeyboard

```
ABCViewController *loginPopUp = [[ABCViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ABCViewController" bundle:Nil];
loginPopUp.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController: loginPopUp animated:NO completion:nil];
```

while click on textfield, keyboard is not raising and screen hangs

Comment: Adding text to explain your problem, the expected result and the result you actually get will help others to help you.

Comment: while click on textfield, keyboard is not raising and screen hangs

Comment: Place this information into your question by editing it so people can comprehend your question quicker.

Comment: I have similar issue, my textField is already set to becomeFirstResponder, I have xyz button in same view. When I tap on xyx button its shows AlertViewController but at that time keyboard being hidden. After cancel the AlertViewController keyboard being appear. Exactly issue is when AlertViewController appear I dont want to hide Keyboard, want to remain in background.

Answer (score 0):

we found a solution for above issue we used UIModalPageFormSheet instead of UIModalPresentationFormSheet. UIModalPageFormSheet is supporting both iOS8 and iOS7.